# Why Can't I Parent Armatures?

Tags: armature, bones, parent

In every tutorial I've looked at, it says that to parent an armature to another one, I select them in the order I want them to be parented and then hit CTRL+P or right-click and select "Parent", "Bone" then  not "keep offset".
But when I try to do this, nothing happens.
[image: My Problem]

Does anyone know why this is?

(In Edit Mode:)
[image: Still My Problem]

Answer (score 1):

You're in pose mode. Parenting must be done in edit mode.

Comment: I tried using Edit Mode, but I had the same problem (just with many fewer confusing options). can I attach a picture to this comment? (I jsut added the new recording to the initial question)

Comment: Don't select them until you;re in edit mode.

Comment: Parenting of bones is in edit mode.  Parenting of *armatures* is in object mode.

Comment: I tried unselecting them in object mode and then selecting them in edit mode (@Ninja Tommy Lee), but it seems like I can't select objects in Edit Mode that I didn't already have selected in object mode, and it autoselects whichever armature i most recently selected or created when I go into Edit Mode.